# Locating a configuration file in distribution independent way?

Tags: linux, unix, autotools

Given a daemon that is built with autotools what is the best way to point the daemon into correct location for configuration files?

I mean depending on the distribution they can reside at least in:

- `/etc/sysconfig`
- `/etc/default`.

Comment: make the configuration directory configurable with a --configure-arg ?

Answer (score 1):

I've used:

```
./configure --sysconfdir=<somewhere> ...
```

Which is what it's for [according to the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html)